# Remove duplicates and get only records with the earliest date in a LINQ expression

Tags: c#, linq

I need help with my code.

I have designed a LINQ query to remove duplicates from my datatable.

The problem is that I need to add an additional filter in which I can filter the duplicates and get only the records with the earliest date.

Like you can see below I have added the orderby in to my query but its throwing an error:

> Instance argument: cannot convert from
> 'System.Linq.IGrouping<AnonymousType#1,System.Data.DataRow>' to
> 'System.Data.DataRow'

and this one:

> System.Linq.IGrouping<AnonymousType#1,System.Data.DataRow>' does not
> contain a definition for 'Field' and the best extension method
> overload 'System.Data.DataRowExtensions.Field(System.Data.DataRow,
> string)' has some invalid arguments

The field which is having the dates but in string format is: x.Field("Effective date")

```
.OrderBy(x => x.Field<string>("Effective date"))
```

I have written some code:

```
ErrorMessage = "";
                CollectionOut = new DataTable();
                DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            try
            {


                dt1 = CollectionIn;

                DataTable dtMerged = dt1.AsEnumerable()
                                    .GroupBy(r => new {d= r.Field<string>("Employee ID"), f=r.Field<string>("Report update date") })
                                    .OrderBy(x => x.Field<string>("Effective date"))
                                    .Select(g => g.First()).CopyToDataTable();
                CollectionOut = dtMerged;
            }
                catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorMessage = ex.Message.ToString();
                
            }
```

I don't know how to solve this issue.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: OrderBy returns an IEnumerable of IGroupings so you can not order by properties of data rows after that step. I think it could already work if you just swap the GroupBy with the OrderBy statement. Don't know about your data base structure but you should probably also take care for empty groups so you should use Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault()).Where(r => r != null).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the below code.

```
DataTable dtMerged = dt1.AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(r => new {d= r.Field<string>("Employee ID"), f=r.Field<string>("Report update date") })
            .Select(g => g.OrderBy(x => x.Field<string>("Effective date")).First()).CopyToDataTable();
```